# long long int type function returning decimal value

Tags: c++, floating-point, int

I wrote a piece of code that will return the square root (without the decimal places i.e floor of the square root) given an integer. But when I am calling it it is giving me a decimal value.Why is this happening? Here is the code `

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

long long int sqrt(long long int a){
    long long int upper = a,lower=0;
    long long int mid = 0;
    while (!(mid*mid >= a and (mid-1)*(mid-1) < a)){
        mid = (lower+upper)/2;
        if(mid*mid > a){
            upper = mid;
        }
        else if(mid*mid <= a){
            lower = mid;
        }
    }
    return mid;

}    
int main(){
    int a;
    while(cin>>a){
        cout<<sqrt(a)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code with g++4.8 and did not see this behavior

Comment: it also seems to be the ceiling rather than floor

Comment: Now your edit just made my answer invalid.

Comment: It probably depends on whether `<iostream>` for some reason includes `<cmath>`, which is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @haccks your answer was always invalid. Moreover it was a typing error.

Comment: 1) put your `sqrt` in a namespace (e.g., `mynamespace`), 2) Initialize `mid` to the proper initial value. 3) call you function like `mynamespace::sqrt`.

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha; Then why only you getting [decimal value](http://ideone.com/3yS9SR) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the problem has been correctly identified in the other answers, but the solutions are not satisfactory. You want all overloads of `sqrt` (your own function and those provided in `namespace std`) to be available and not require any scope resolution like `mymath::sqrt`.

The solution must look at the function call. You essentially have

```
long long int sqrt(long long int);  // your function
float sqrt(float);                  // from namespace std
double sqrt(double);                // from namespace std
long double sqrt(long double);      // from namespace std
double sqrt(integral_type);         // from namespace std in C++11
```

Since you call `sqrt(int)` the last overload will be picked (if you have C++11) and the 3rd otherwise. In order to pick your own function you must call it:

```
int main(){
    long long int a;
    while(cin>>a) {
        cout<<sqrt(a)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting `std::sqrt` here instead of the `::sqrt` you defined.  Depending on the C++ implementation you're using, qualifying your `sqrt` call as `::sqrt` might work.  Better yet, call your custom `sqrt` something else and call it directly.

Answer (score 2):

- Microsoft implemented the `<iostream>` header in way that indirectly includes `<cmath>` header.
- This is not a bug, the C++ standard doesn't dictate that indirect inclusion of other STL headers in a STL header is forbidden.
- As such, this indirect inclusion of header `<cmath>` shadows your `sqrt`.
- In other compilers like [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9498dba9a28cd12e) or [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be3e92ce5caf4323) you don't experience such a behaviour.

### Solution:

1. Put your `sqrt` function in a separate namespace (e.g., `mymath`).
2. Call your function in code as `mymath::sqrt`.

---

```
#include<iostream>

namespace mymath {
  long long int sqrt(long long int a) {
    long long int upper = a;
    long long int lower = 0;
    long long int mid   = 0;

    while (!(mid * mid >= a && (mid - 1) * (mid - 1) < a)){
      mid = (lower + upper) / 2;
      if (mid * mid > a){
        upper = mid;
      } else if (mid * mid <= a){
        lower = mid;
      }
    }
    return mid;
  }
}

int main(){
  int a;
  while (std::cin >> a){
    std::cout << mymath::sqrt(a) << std::endl;
  }
}
```